# Firefox terminates if multiple instances of flash player running

Tags: linux, firefox, flash-player

If i have, say, youtube tab opened and if a click on some of the related videos (while it's still playing) firefox terminates. The same if I open youtube on one tab and myspace on another - firefox just shuts down.

I want to know why this happens, is it a bug and how can i fix it ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue with some combinations of versions of flashplayer / firefox. A workaround is to use [flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433) and explicitly turn on flash objects when you want to interact with them - this also speeds up page load, and makes firefox much more usable.

Answer (score 0):

What version of flash player are you using? Check your plugin status here for Firefox:

http://www.mozilla.com/plugincheck/

And see if that's the problem.

Comment: OK, I think that may be a beta version. As the latest version I have on file is 10.0.45.0. Go to www.ninite.com and grab an installer for the latest Flash and Flash(IE) and install them to see if that helps.